# how to find the line of best fit for precision recall curves in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have calculated points for a recall-precision curve by varying a threshold and calculating recall and precision. I have plotted these points in a scatter graph as follows:

```
scatter(recall', precision')
```

I am trying to find the curve of best fit, but am not sure of the best way. I have tried this:

```
p = polyfit(recall', precision', 5)
r = polyval(p, recall')
plot(recall', precision', 'x');
hold on
plot(recall', r, '-');
hold off
```

But the problem with this is I have to estimate the degree of the polynomial (in this case 5).

Answer (score 1):

you can try the program **Eureqa Formulize**. Its a free and easy to use tool for symbolic regression developed at **Cornell Creative Machines Lab**.

Regards,
Ben

Comment: Sure. Here is the download link

http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa_download

and a quick intro video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6QtDzaMc3p0

Comment: Eureqa is marketed by a company called Nutonian. The software is definitely NOT free. What is free, though, is an evaluation version that expires after 30 days. Just to avoid misunderstandings... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to take the logarithm of recall and precision variables and fit a line through them. The slope then should give a rough idea about the degree of the polynomial you might want to use, i.e.

```
p2 = polyfit(log(recall), log(precision), 1)
```